# In Drupal 7, how do I get a list of all blocks being used in the entire website

Tags: drupal-7

I need to see the pages (panels) a block is being used.

Since I use *panels*, I can't just use the blocks' page to check where a block is used.

I have seen something similar for a list of all *fields* being used in the entire website, is there anything similar for blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such functionality by default. But there are some methods to do this. Check this answer **"[In Drupal 7, how do I get a list of all blocks being used on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673773/in-drupal-7-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-blocks-being-used-on-the-page)"**